# F# Multidimensional Array Types

Tags: f#, multidimensional-array

What's the difference between `'a[,,]` and `'a[][][]`? They both represent 3-d arrays.
It makes me write `array3d.[x].[y].[z]` instead of `array3d.[x, y, z]`.

Why I can't do the following?

```
> let array2d : int[,] = Array2D.zeroCreate 10 10;;
> let array1d = array2d.[0];;

error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type
    'a []    
but here has type
    int [,]
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The difference is that `'a[][]` represents an array of arrays (of possibly different lengths), while in `'a[,]`, represents a rectangular 2D array. The first type is also called *jagged arrays* and the second type is called *multidimensional arrays*. The difference is the same as in C#, so you may want to look at the C# documentation for [jagged arrays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca(v=VS.100).aspx) and [multidimensional arrays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4(v=VS.100).aspx). There is also an excelent documentation in the [F# WikiBook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/F_Sharp_Programming/Arrays).

To demonstrate this using a picture, a value of type `'a[][]` can look like this:

```
0 1 2 3 4
5 6
7 8 9 0 1
```

While a value of type `a[,]` will always be a rectangle and may look for example like this:

```
0 1 2 3
4 5 6 7
8 9 0 1
```

---

To get a single "line" of a multidimensional array, you can use the *slice notation*:

```
let row = array2d.[0,*];;
```

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/arrays#array-slicing-and-multidimensional-arrays

Answer (score 6):

As of F# 3.1 (2013) things are simpler:

> As of F# 3.1, you can decompose a multidimensional array into subarrays of the same or lower dimension. For example, you can obtain a vector from a matrix by specifying a single row or column.
>
> ```
> // Get row 3 from a matrix as a vector:
> matrix.[3, *]
>
> // Get column 3 from a matrix as a vector:
> matrix.[*, 3]
> ```

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/arrays#array-slicing-and-multidimensional-arrays